# « Une fois de plus » et « encore une fois »

Tags: anglais, sens, choix-de-mot, comparaison-de-langues

Quelle est la différence entre « une fois de plus » et « encore une fois » ? Est-ce que c'est approximativement la même différence subtile qu'entre « *one more time* » et « *once more* » ?

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il y est une différence marquante entre ces deux expressions qui signifient seulement la réptition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bien qu'elles soient semblables dans l'acte accompli, on  peut noter une différence dans l'intention :

- Vous pouvez faire *une fois de plus* autant de *fois* qu'il est nécessaire pour arriver à vos fins. Le nombre d'actions est déterminé par la progression du résultat.
- Vous sollicitez *encore une fois*, pour que l'action soit finie. C'est la dernière ou l'avant-dernière *fois*.

Answer (score 8):

**"Une fois de plus"** tend a exprimer le fait que la repetition est prévisible, voire inevitable ... en anglais, c'est plus proche de **"Yet again"**.

**"encore une fois"** n'a pas cette connotation et s'utilise souvent pour demander/solliciter la repetition ... en anglais c'est plus proche de Britney spear dans "Hit me baby **one more time**!" :)