# Difference between "encore" "plus" and "davantage?"

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

My first post, but I have been watching for a while.

I am trying to write a sentence with the meaning of "to explain to you in more detail would take more time than I have right now, so let's just leave it there for now".

1. Pour aller plus a fond dans les détails il me faudrait encore du temps/ plus de temps/ davantage de temps. Alors restons-en là pour le moment/ pour aujourd'hui.

2.Entrer dans les détails nécessiterait encore du temps/ plus de temps/ davantage de temps... etc.

I am not too bothered about the first bit although I expect some things sound more natural than others. However it just struck me that I don’t know the difference between “davantage” “encore” “plus” ? Maybe there isn’t one and they are interchangeable? Can anyone help? Also feel free to correct the other bits if you can think of a better way to put it.

Comment: "Alors restons là …" and "Alors restons-en là …" mean two different things; are you  certain that what you want to say is not expressed by the second form?

Answer (score 3):

“*Plus de X*” and “*davantage de X*” (where *X* is a noun without an article) are completely synonymous. “*Plus de X*” is more common. You may occasionally find people who forbid “*davantage de/que*” and only allow *davantage* as a standalone adverb, but even the very conservative [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/davantage) allows them. Note that “*plus de*” is pronounced [plys]: [the S is not silent when *plus* means more](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/268/when-does-one-pronounce-the-s-in-plus).

“*Encore du temps*” is almost synonymous, but there is a subtle difference which may or may not make it inapplicable. I perceive the difference intuitively as a native speaker and I'll try to explain but I'm not completely sure I've captured the difference correctly. The meaning of “*encore*” always includes some nuance of “again” and not just “more”. It can mean adding more to what's already there, but not just adding more to a certain quantity. In your first sentence, if you're currently giving a presentation and want to say that you cannot go into details because you've run out of time, you can say either “*il me faudrait plus de temps*” or “*il me faudrait encore du temps*”. But if you're preparing a presentation and you decide to cut a topic because you don't have enough time, only “*il me faudrait plus de temps*” works.

This is not specific to time. For example, *encore* works in the first context below but not in the second context:

> *Je sens que la pâte est trop dure. Il faudrait plus d'eau.*   (I can feel that the dough is too hard. It needs more water.) [Context: while baking, I've already put some water.]
>
> *Je sens que la pâte est trop dure. Il faudrait encore de l'eau.*   (I can feel that the dough is too hard. It needs more water.) [Context: while baking, I've already put some water.]
>
> *Un verre d'eau ne suffit pas pour cette recette. Il faut plus d'eau.*   (One glass of water is not enough for this recipe. It needs more water.) [Context: discussing a recipe.]

Answer (score 0):

All three are quite interchangeable. The difference between *plus* and *davantage* is mostly formality and has already been answered here:
[Davantage/plus - what's the difference?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36488/davantage-plus-whats-the-difference).

*Encore* might suggest that's not the first time extra time has been needed for the task.

Note that both *plus* and *davantage* use ***de** temps* but *encore* uses ***du** temps*:

> *Il me faudrait plus **de** temps*

> *Il me faudrait davantage **de** temps*

> *Il me faudrait encore **du** temps*

See also: [« Une fois de plus » et « encore une fois »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9489/une-fois-de-plus-et-encore-une-fois)